# Fail to plot by group on a phyloseq object generated by R package Divnet

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I intend to plot an alpha diversity plot of my samples, which consist of three groups.
Alpha diversity is calculated by R package Divnet. It involve using phyloseq as a dependency.

The group of each sample is specified in a sam_data, column "type" in phyloseq object "df_family"
"dv" is list composed of diversity estimates and standard errors.

Here is the code I used:

```
dv$shannon %>% plot(df_family, color = "type", group = df_family@sam_data$type) +
 xlab("sample type") +
 ylab("Shannon diversity estimate (family level)") +
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5))`
```

Here is what I get:

The samples were shown independently, instead of clustered as a group
[image: my plot1]

Here is what I intend to get:
[image: intended plot2]

Answer (score 1):

Once you already have your phyloseq object `df_family`, you can use the function `estimate_richness` from phyloseq.
You can then join the sample meta data to this data frame of alpha diversities.
Finally, you can use `ggplot2` directly to customize your plot accordingly, e.g. to put different sample groups (here `SampleType`) at your x axis:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(phyloseq)

# get example phy object
otufile <- system.file("extdata", "GP_otu_table_rand_short.txt.gz", package = "phyloseq")
mapfile <- system.file("extdata", "master_map.txt", package = "phyloseq")
df_family <- import_qiime(otufile, mapfile, trefile, showProgress = FALSE)

alphadiv <-
  df_family %>%
  estimate_richness() %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "sample_id") %>%
  left_join(df_family@sam_data %>% as_tibble(rownames = "sample_id"))
alphadiv

alphadiv %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = SampleType, y = Shannon)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

You can also add additional sample properties in aes e.g. `aes(x = SampleType, y = Shannon, color = my_group)` if `my_group` is a sample property column with cells containing f, li, or si.